# iOS How to Store C++ Object into a NSArray used as a tableview's datasource

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c++

Recently, I encountered a problem: in my tableview, I retrieve data from web request, after received response from the network, I need to decode the data and store the data in a C++ object.

However, the tableview datasource, NSArray cannot store C++ object.

I have tried some solutions, like using CFMutableArrayRef or save the C++ object pointer in a NSValue and then put the NSValue into the NSArray. But when I called [tableview reloadData],the data in the CFMutableArray or the NSValue don't have the right data.

Could anybody help me with this problem? Thanks!

Here are some code:

```
std::list<ImageTextContent> msgs = body->getMsgs();
std::list<ImageTextContent>::iterator itmsgs0;
for(itmsgs0 = msgs.begin();itmsgs0 != msgs.end();itmsgs0++)
{
    ImageTextContent *tmpmsgs = &(*itmsgs0);
    CFArrayAppendValue(_dataSourceRef, tmpmsgs);

}
```

and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ImageTextContent *itc = (ImageTextContent *)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(_dataSourceRef, 0);
    NSString *title = [NSString stringWithCString:(itc->getSubmitTime()).c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    cell.contentLabel.text = title;

    ....
}
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath method I can't get the right data, why?

Comment: Why not just save the results of your web request as objective-c objects in an NSArray? Your objects could even be instances of NSDictionary

Comment: In any case, you need to return a properly configured UITableViewCell from *tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:*. What's the rest of this method?

Comment: @nielsbot because the response data must be decoded by using thrift, and the decode code are written in C++, so...

Comment: @nielsbot, hi, I have updated the code. Just get the data in the C++ object and assign it to the cell text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointers in your `_dataSourceRef` array become invalid as soon as the lifetime of `msgs` ends.

Dereferencing any of them is undefined at that point and anything can happen.
(Very common is that the data has been overwritten and you just find some random stuff there.)

Either make `getMsgs` return a list of pointers, or dynamically allocate a copy the data when you populate the array, like this:

```
for(itmsgs0 = msgs.begin();itmsgs0 != msgs.end();itmsgs0++)
{
    CFArrayAppendValue(_dataSourceRef, new ImageTextContent(*itmsgs0));
}
```

Comment: You could set up your CFArray to automatically copy on insert and deallocate on remove by filling out the *callBacks* param of *CFArrayCreate()*